# Шпаргалка по кодам и соотношениям HRESULT к исключениям в .NET (winapi)

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi, clr

Иногда поиск ошибки по числовому значению отнимает довольно много времени, нашел шпаргалку по ошибкам HRESULTS, подробности в ответе.

Comment: А что, `FormatMessage` уже не работает?...

Comment: `FormatMessage` - далеко не всегда под рукой, а для внедрения нужно все пере собирать, что есть время..

Comment: `Main menu` → `Tools` → `Error lookup`

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не является вопросом

Comment: @Harry, `MessageFormat` кроме всего прочего ничего не знает об этих кодах, и отдает пустую строку на них, по крайней мере у меня (VS2017 со всеми апдейтами)

Comment: `Error lookup` действительно не присутствует в русском варианте VS, возможно надо что то дополнительно выбрать в установке, вообще это файл `ErrLook.exe` в корневой директории VS. Но он в данном случае бесполезен почти больше чем полностью, он основан на `FormatMessage()` с флагом `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`

Comment: Есть аналог ErrorLookup для Hresult, правда довольно древний, и в нем тоже не полная информация, но вполне работоспособен: http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/ShowHresult/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HRESULT - это 32-битное значение, разделенное на три поля: код
>   серьезности, код объекта и код ошибки. Код серьезности указывает,
>   представляет ли возвращаемое значение информацию, предупреждение или
>   ошибку. Код объекта идентифицирует область системы, ответственную за
>   ошибку.

**HRESULT Used range**:

> Reflection use 0x1600 -> 0x161f
>   IO use 0x1620 -> 0x163f
>   Security use 0x1640 -> 0x165f

**HRESULT IO**:

```
COR_E_ENDOFSTREAM 0x80070026  // OS defined
COR_E_FILELOAD 0x80131621
COR_E_FILENOTFOUND 0x80070002
COR_E_DIRECTORYNOTFOUND 0x80070003
COR_E_PATHTOOLONG 0x800700CE
COR_E_IO 0x80131620
```

**HRESULT mscorlib**:

```
RO_E_CLOSED 0x80000013
E_BOUNDS 0x8000000B
E_CHANGED_STATE 0x8000000C
E_FAIL 0x80004005 
E_POINTER 0x80004003 
E_NOTIMPL 0x80004001
REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG 0x80040154
COR_E_AMBIGUOUSMATCH 0x8000211D 
COR_E_APPDOMAINUNLOADED 0x80131014 
COR_E_APPLICATION 0x80131600 
COR_E_ARGUMENT 0x80070057 
COR_E_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE 0x80131502 
COR_E_ARITHMETIC 0x80070216 
COR_E_ARRAYTYPEMISMATCH 0x80131503      
COR_E_BADIMAGEFORMAT 0x8007000B     
COR_E_TYPEUNLOADED 0x80131013 
COR_E_CANNOTUNLOADAPPDOMAIN 0x80131015 
COR_E_COMEMULATE 0x80131535 
COR_E_CONTEXTMARSHAL 0x80131504 
COR_E_DATAMISALIGNED 0x80131541
COR_E_TIMEOUT 0x80131505        
COR_E_CUSTOMATTRIBUTEFORMAT 0x80131605 
COR_E_DIVIDEBYZERO 0x80020012 // DISP_E_DIVBYZERO
COR_E_DUPLICATEWAITOBJECT 0x80131529
COR_E_EXCEPTION 0x80131500 
COR_E_EXECUTIONENGINE 0x80131506 
COR_E_FIELDACCESS 0x80131507 
COR_E_FORMAT 0x80131537 
COR_E_INDEXOUTOFRANGE 0x80131508 
COR_E_INSUFFICIENTMEMORY 0x8013153D
COR_E_INSUFFICIENTEXECUTIONSTACK 0x80131578
COR_E_INVALIDCAST 0x80004002 
COR_E_INVALIDCOMOBJECT 0x80131527
COR_E_INVALIDFILTERCRITERIA 0x80131601 
COR_E_INVALIDOLEVARIANTTYPE 0x80131531   
COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION 0x80131509 
COR_E_INVALIDPROGRAM 0x8013153A 
COR_E_KEYNOTFOUND 0x80131577
COR_E_MARSHALDIRECTIVE 0x80131535 
COR_E_MEMBERACCESS 0x8013151A 
COR_E_METHODACCESS 0x80131510 
COR_E_MISSINGFIELD 0x80131511 
COR_E_MISSINGMANIFESTRESOURCE 0x80131532
COR_E_MISSINGMEMBER 0x80131512
COR_E_MISSINGMETHOD 0x80131513 
COR_E_MISSINGSATELLITEASSEMBLY 0x80131536
COR_E_MULTICASTNOTSUPPORTED 0x80131514 
COR_E_NOTFINITENUMBER 0x80131528
COR_E_PLATFORMNOTSUPPORTED 0x80131539 
COR_E_NOTSUPPORTED 0x80131515 
COR_E_NULLREFERENCE 0x80004003 
COR_E_OBJECTDISPOSED 0x80131622
COR_E_OPERATIONCANCELED 0x8013153B
COR_E_OUTOFMEMORY 0x8007000E 
COR_E_OVERFLOW 0x80131516 
COR_E_RANK 0x80131517 
COR_E_REFLECTIONTYPELOAD    0x80131602 
COR_E_RUNTIMEWRAPPED 0x8013153E
COR_E_SAFEARRAYRANKMISMATCH 0x80131538 
COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH 0x80131533 
COR_E_SAFEHANDLEMISSINGATTRIBUTE 0x80131623
COR_E_SECURITY 0x8013150A 
COR_E_SERIALIZATION 0x8013150C
COR_E_SEMAPHOREFULL 0x8013152B
COR_E_WAITHANDLECANNOTBEOPENED 0x8013152C
COR_E_ABANDONEDMUTEX 0x8013152D
COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW 0x800703E9 
COR_E_SYNCHRONIZATIONLOCK 0x80131518 
COR_E_SYSTEM 0x80131501 
COR_E_TARGET 0x80131603 
COR_E_TARGETINVOCATION 0x80131604 
COR_E_TARGETPARAMCOUNT 0x8002000e
COR_E_THREADABORTED 0x80131530 
COR_E_THREADINTERRUPTED 0x80131519 
COR_E_THREADSTATE 0x80131520 
COR_E_THREADSTOP 0x80131521 
COR_E_THREADSTART 0x80131525
COR_E_TYPEACCESS 0x80131543
COR_E_TYPEINITIALIZATION 0x80131534 
COR_E_TYPELOAD 0x80131522 
COR_E_ENTRYPOINTNOTFOUND 0x80131523 
COR_E_DLLNOTFOUND 0x80131524 
COR_E_UNAUTHORIZEDACCESS 0x80070005 
COR_E_UNSUPPORTEDFORMAT 0x80131523 
COR_E_VERIFICATION 0x8013150D 
COR_E_HOSTPROTECTION 0x80131640
CORSEC_E_MIN_GRANT_FAIL 0x80131417
CORSEC_E_NO_EXEC_PERM 0x80131418
CORSEC_E_POLICY_EXCEPTION 0x80131416
CORSEC_E_XMLSYNTAX 0x80131418
NTE_FAIL 0x80090020 
CORSEC_E_CRYPTO 0x80131430
CORSEC_E_CRYPTO_UNEX_OPER 0x80131431
DISP_E_OVERFLOW 0x8002000a
FUSION_E_REF_DEF_MISMATCH 0x80131040
FUSION_E_INVALID_NAME 0x80131047
TYPE_E_TYPEMISMATCH 0x80028ca0
```

**соотношение HRESULT и Исключений .NET**:

```
HRESULT                 |     .NET Exception

MSEE_E_APPDOMAINUNLOADED AppDomainUnloadedException
COR_E_APPLICATION ApplicationException
COR_E_ARGUMENT ArgumentException
COR_E_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE ArgumentOutOfRangeException
COR_E_ARITHMETIC ArithmeticException
COR_E_ARRAYTYPEMISMATCH ArrayTypeMismatchException
COR_E_BADIMAGEFORMAT  BadImageFormatException
COR_E_COMEMULATE_ERROR COMEmulateException
COR_E_CONTEXTMARSHAL ContextMarshalException
COR_E_CORE CoreException
COR_E_DIRECTORYNOTFOUND DirectoryNotFoundException 
COR_E_DIVIDEBYZERO DivideByZeroException
COR_E_DUPLICATEWAITOBJECT DuplicateWaitObjectException
COR_E_ENDOFSTREAM EndOfStreamException
COR_E_TYPELOAD EntryPointNotFoundException
COR_E_EXCEPTION Exception
COR_E_EXECUTIONENGINE ExecutionEngineException
COR_E_FIELDACCESS FieldAccessException
COR_E_FILENOTFOUND FileNotFoundException
COR_E_FORMAT FormatException
COR_E_INDEXOUTOFRANGE IndexOutOfRangeException
COR_E_INVALIDCAST InvalidCastException
COR_E_INVALIDCOMOBJECT InvalidComObjectException
COR_E_INVALIDFILTERCRITERIA InvalidFilterCriteriaException
COR_E_INVALIDOLEVARIANTTYPE InvalidOleVariantTypeException
COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION InvalidOperationException
COR_E_IO IOException
COR_E_MEMBERACCESS AccessException
COR_E_METHODACCESS MethodAccessException
COR_E_MISSINGFIELD MissingFieldException
COR_E_MISSINGMANIFESTRESOURCE MissingManifestResourceException
COR_E_MISSINGMEMBER MissingMemberException
COR_E_MISSINGMETHOD MissingMethodException
COR_E_MULTICASTNOTSUPPORTED MulticastNotSupportedException
COR_E_NOTFINITENUMBER NotFiniteNumberException
COR_E_NOTSUPPORTED NotSupportedException
COR_E_NULLREFERENCE  NullReferenceException
COR_E_OUTOFMEMORY OutOfMemoryException
COR_E_OVERFLOW OverflowException
COR_E_PATHTOOLONG PathTooLongException
COR_E_RANK RankException
COR_E_REFLECTIONTYPELOAD ReflectionTypeLoadException
COR_E_REMOTING RemotingException
COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH SafeArrayTypeMismatchException
COR_E_SECURITY SecurityException
COR_E_SERIALIZATION SerializationException
COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW StackOverflowException
COR_E_SYNCHRONIZATIONLOCK SynchronizationLockException
COR_E_SYSTEM SystemException
COR_E_TARGET TargetException
COR_E_TARGETINVOCATION TargetInvocationException
COR_E_TARGETPARAMCOUNT TargetParameterCountException
COR_E_THRE AD ABORTED ThreadAbortException
COR_E_THREADINTERRUPTED ThreadInterruptedException
COR_E_THREADSTATE ThreadStateException
COR_E_THREADSTOP ThreadStopException
COR_E_TYPELOAD TypeLoadException
COR_E_TYPEINITIALIZATION TypeInitializationException
COR_E_VERIFICATION VerificationException
COR_E_WEAKREFERENCE WeakReferenceException
COR_E_VTABLECALLSNOTSUPPORTED VTableCallsNotSupportedException

E_NOTIMPL NotImplementedException
E_POINTER NullReferenceException
E_OUTOFMEMORY OutOfMemoryException
E_NOINTERFACE InvalidCastException
E_INVALIDARG ArgumentException
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND DirectoryNotFoundException
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND FileNotFoundException
ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE PathTooLongException
ERROR_STACK_OVERFLOW StackOverflowException
ERROR_BAD_FORMAT BadImageFormatException
ERROR_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW ArithmeticException
NTE_FAIL CryptographicException

All other HRESULTs COMException_
```

**COM / IErrorInfo interface**:

```
COM Interop Extended Error Information

Exception      Информация об источнике COM
ErrorCode      Возвращаемый HRESULT из вызываемого метода
HelpLink       Если IErrorInfo->HelpContext отличен от нуля,
               строка формируется путем объединения IErrorInfo->GetHelpFile + "#"
               и IErrorInfo->GetHelpContext.
               В противном случае строка возвращается из IErrorInfo->GetHelpFile
InnerException Всегда ноль
Message        Строка возвращаемая из IErrorInfo->GetDescription
Source         Строка возвращаемая из IErrorInfo->GetSource
StackTrace     .NET генерация трассировки стека для этого исключения
TargetSite     Имя метода из которого HRESULT был возвращен в коде .NET
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-ierrorinfo

**Проверка HRESULT со стороны C#**

```
try {
    ...

} catch (COMException ce) {
    if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x800A03AA)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Ценность находок в том что в поиске по номеру ошибки оно как правило находиться далеко не на первых страницах.

Собственно url списка констант HRESULT взяты тут: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/__hresults.cs,c4f0369b78643cb0  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__hresults.cs

Таблица соотношений HRESULT и Исключений .NET
https://www.visualbasicplanet.info/csharp-code/handling-interop-errors.html

Приведенные здесь значения не входят в официальный список на MSDN [2.1.1 Значения HRESULT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/705fb797-2175-4a90-b5a3-3918024b10b8)

Comment: Вот еще есть: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/705fb797-2175-4a90-b5a3-3918024b10b8

Comment: Ну кто же дает ответ просто как ссылку?... Здесь принято давать ответ именно на сайте, чтоб даже если ссылка "уплывет"/станет недоступной/etc - ответ остался.

Comment: Можно и вставить конечно, но если оно уплывет у MS - значит оно уплыло совсем :) вместе с API. Позднее выберу время и перенесу константы сюда, отредактировав.

Comment: Кстати, эта ссылка в MS не содержит коды возврата `mscorlib`, например `COR_E_TARGETINVOCATION` код `0x80131604`, как и других кодов из этой сборки. Так что находка актуальная.

Comment: Потому что та страница довольно старая, CLR стал частью Windows только начиная с висты. Коды возврата CLR документированы в разрозненных статьях по исключениям, например [COR_E_TARGETINVOCATION](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception?view=netcore-1.1), но сводной таблицы действительно нету. В исходниках .NET, увы, они тоже разрознены, помимо вашей ссылки есть например еще https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__hresults.cs и другие

Comment: Сводную таблицу, скорее всего, лучше бы составлять на гитхабе, а не здесь, так как там поддерживается расширенный синтакисис markdown для таблиц.